# How to get javascript to work on every page

Tags: javascript, function, jquery-mobile

I'm currently working on a small app, and I'm trying to implement a dropdown menu on a multipage structured page. The menu is javascript based, and I've basically pasted the the menu onto every page.
The problem is that once I enter #page2 or #page3 via the dropdown menu, the script stops working and the menu wont respond when I click on it.

I guess the question here is; how do I get the script to work on not only #page 1, but #page2 and page #3 as well?

Here is the HTML:

```
<body>

<div data-role="page" id="page1">

<div id="push"><a href="" id="info_drop"></a></div>

<div id="dd" data-position="fixed" class="wrapper-dropdown-5"><li>Om oss</li> 
</div>

<div id="panel">

    <ul class="dropdown">
    <a href="#"><li>Om festivalen</li></a>
    <a href="#page2" rel="external"><li>Praktisk info</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li>Administrasjon</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li>Frivillig</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li>Samarbeidspartnere</li></a>
    </ul>


    </div>


<div id="info_content">

sup

</div>
</div>


<div data-role="page" id="page2">

-- same html as in page 1 ----

</div>


<script src="dropdown_js.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2
/jquery.min.js">
</script>

</body>
```

The javascript:

```
$(function (){
$(".wrapper-dropdown-5").bind('click tap', function() {
$("#panel").stop().slideToggle("fast");
$("#info_content").stop().animate({"margin-top":"10px"}, "fast")
}, function() {
$("#info_content").stop().animate({"margin-top":"0"}, "slow")
$("#panel").stop().slideToggle("fast");
});
});
```

EDIT: 
This is my css:

```
.wrapper-dropdown-5 {
/* Size & position */
position: relative;
width: 200px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 12px 15px;

/* Styles */
background: #fff;
border-radius: 5px;
}



.wrapper-dropdown-5 .dropdown {
/* Size & position */
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
left: 0;
right: 0;

/* Styles */
background: #fff;

/* Hiding */
max-height: 0;
overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper-dropdown-5 .dropdown li {
padding: 0 10px ;
}

.wrapper-dropdown-5 .dropdown li a {
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
color: #333;
padding: 10px 0;
}



.wrapper-dropdown-5 .dropdown li i {
margin-right: 5px;
color: inherit;
vertical-align: middle;
}


/* Active state */

.wrapper-dropdown-5.active .dropdown {
max-height: 400px;
}
```

Comment: Instead of having a file called dropdown_js.js, have the javascript on the same file. Also have the javascript in the `<head>` tag.

Comment: already tried that. didnt do anything

Comment: Does dropdown.js depend on jquery? if so, you need to include jquery first, then dropdown.js. Also try using firebug(firefox plugin) and checking the console log for errors.

Comment: Would you be able to post your css? I will try to get it to work for you.

Comment: just added the CSS to the original post. Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All HTML element IDs need to be different. It looks to me like you've got the same ids, `panel` and `info_content`, on all 3 pages; the browser is only paying attention to the first one of each, i.e. the ones on page 1. (Actually the behaviour in this case may be browser-dependent.) So you need to give them different IDs. And, of course, you also need to distinguish between the `.wrapper-dropdown-5` elements.